Proof complexity of Sudoku
Let $P$ be a $N$x$N$ Sudoku puzzle
(assume $N=n^2$ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$,
e.g. standard $9$x$9$ puzzle is $n=3$).
We can represent it in propositional logic as follows:
Variables

$p_{i,j,k}$: value of cell $(i,j)$ is $k$ (for $1 \leq i,j,k \leq N$)

Clauses

each cell has exactly one value:

for $i,j\in[N]$, clause
$$\bigvee_{k} p_{i,j,k}$$

for $i,j\in[N]$, for $k\neq k' \in [N]$, clause
$$\lnot p_{i,j,k} \vee \lnot p_{i,j,k'}$$



each group of cells in a row (or column or box) $S$, each value $k$ appears exactly once:

for $S\subset [N]\times[N]$ a row/col/box, for $k\in[N]$, caluses
$$\bigvee_{(i,j)\in S} p_{i,j,k}$$

for $S\subset [N]\times[N]$ a row/col/box, for $k\in[N]$, for $(i,j)\neq(i',j')\in S$ caluse
$$\lnot p_{i,j,k} \vee \lnot p_{i',j',k}$$




It is easy to see that the puzzle has a solution iff the above set of caluses are satisfiable.
It is known that the generalized Sudoku is NP-complete.
So there are unsatisfiable cases that have no poly-size propositional proofs
(in any fixed Cook-Reckhow proof system)
(unless NP=coNP).
One can find such instances by encoding hard instances for the proof system in question using the mapping from SAT to generalized Sudoku.
I am looking for simple explicit examples of the problem that are hard for refutation resolution proof system with explicit proof of hardness (similar to say the hardness proofs for Pigeon Hole Principle).
Are there instances of Sudoku that are intuitively easy to see that they are not satisfiable (e.g. based on some simple combinatorial principle, and without going through encoding), but with exponential size resolution refutation proofs?
